# Check in view what page the user is on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way in Rails to check which page a user is currently viewing?

my example: In the head section of my website I need to know if a user has opened a blog post. If a user is viewing a post then in the head section facebook open graph meta tags need to be added because user has the option to like the blog post.

It would be invaluable if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers mention you can check current page by examining `request` object or `params` hash.

But there is better way to set up Facebook meta tags without explicitely checking page context. `content_for` helper method is a perfect hit here. See the docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

Basically, `content_for` takes a block as argument and captures the output which can be displayed elsewhere with `yield`.

So you can capture some content in your views:

```
# index.html.erb (blog index)
<% content_for :facebook_meta do %>
  <meta content='My blog' property='og:site_name'>
  ...
<% end %>


# show.html.erb (single blog post)
<% content_for :facebook_meta do %>
  <meta content='<%= @post.title %>' property='og:site_name'>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And display them in layout:

```
# application.html.erb (application layout)
<html>
  <head>
    <%= yield :facebook_meta %>
  </head>
</html>
```

The above is much cleaner than checking current controller/action in this scenario. You only define Facebook meta tags in places they apply to.

Answer (score 1):

With help from Radar in the #RubyOnRails IRC channel, I used the following code:

`params[:action]` and `params[:controller]`

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the context of the request (action, controller, headers...) using the request helper that is available in the controller

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Comment: Should probably provide brief example code or API links with this.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could help me with the code itself. I am quite new with RoR in general. Here is the example of a URL when a blog post is viewed: http://my-site.herokuapp.com/blog/posts/junior-dos-santos. "junior-dos-santos" is the post title, I believe "blog" is a controller, and "posts" action (I'm not sure for controller and action)

Comment: I agree with Andrew Marshall - some sample code would be helpful.